# TeXShop and MacTeX-2019: error

Tags: texshop, mactex, macos

I have just downloaded and installed successfully MacTeX-2019. However when opening TeXShop I receive the following message

> "TeXShop ne peut pas s’ouvrir en raison d’un problème".

Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. 
I will assume that your MacTeX2019 installation procedure automatically set up the following two front-end editors: TeXshop and TeXworks. What happens if you click on the TeXworks icon? Do you get an error message as well? If so, which one? And, do please tell us which MacOS version is installed on your computer.

Comment: Additionally, which version of TeXShop are you running?

Comment: TeXWorks is not included in MacTeX-2019. What OS version are you using? You will need the latest version to initially open properly under Catalina. You can download it from <[https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html]>.

Comment: Sorry, that link should be <https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html>.

Comment: If you are using Catalina and wish,  try the following: Copy and paste the command `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ` (note the space at the end of the command) into a Terminal window; then drag and drop TeXShop.app onto that window; finally press return. See if TeXShop then starts up.